# How to replace the contents of a page with an iframe containing the contents of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a chrome extension that places the contents of the current page into one iframe, and the contents of another page into another iframe, and show them side-by-side (both iframes are `width:50%;float:left`).

What I've got is:

```
var h = jQuery('html');
h.html('<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape(h.html()) + '" style="width:50%; float:left;"></iframe><iframe src="...');
```

My problem is it is not rendering css or loading the js.

As a stop-gap I am setting the `src` attribute as the `location.href`, but that is only doing a `GET` of the current page, the contents of which may change on `POST`.

How do I get the iframe to render the css and js?

Comment: I don't mind the down-votes, as long as they're accompanied with constructive comments. **Why am I being down voted?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the resources of the iframe being unable to work out what the host is. As such, because my references are all relative, they could not work out the full path. I.e. I have set the `src` of the iframe to a string of HTML, and the css path is similar to `/css/styles.css` - it cannot resolve `/css/styles.css` relative to the string of HTML.

The solution is add a `<base href="" />` tag to the head of the HTML:

```
h.find('head').prepend('<base href="'+location.origin+'"/>');
```

The full script now looks like:

```
var h = jQuery('html');
h.find('head').prepend('<base href="'+location.origin+'"/>');
h.html('<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape(h.html()) + '" style="width:50%; float:left;"></iframe><iframe src="...');
```

The `base` tag is telling all the relative urls to prepend the `href` attribute to themselves; i.e. turn the relative css url from `/css/styles.css` to `http://example.com/css/styles.css`

Comment: Depending on your usage you may encounter websites that will apply framebusting, i.e. detect being loaded in an iframe, and then reload in _top, or refuse to load, etc (either as a security measure or for any other reason having to do with control).